# Parsing Dynamic Json in Swift

Tags: json, swift, dynamic

```
{
  "AAPL" : {
    "quote": {...},
    "news": [...],
    "chart": [...]
  },
  "FB" : {
    "quote": {...},
    "news": [...],
    "chart": [...]
  },
}
```

How would you decode this in swift. The stocks change but the underlying quote, news, and chart stay the same. Also to mention this json of stocks could be 500 long with unknown sorting order.

For the information in quote it would look like:

```
{

"calculationPrice": "tops",
"open": 154,
ect...

}
```

inside news:

```
[
  {
    "datetime": 1545215400000,
    "headline": "Voice Search Technology Creates A New Paradigm For 
     Marketers",
     ect...
  }
]
```

Inside charts:

```
[
    {
        "date": "2017-04-03",
        "open": 143.1192,
        ect...
    } 
]
```

What I have been trying is something along the lines of this as an example...

Json Response:

```
{
  "kolsh" : {
    "description" : "First only brewed in Köln, Germany, now many American brewpubs..."
  },
  "stout" : {
    "description" : "As mysterious as they look, stouts are typically dark brown to pitch black in color..."
  }
}
```

Struct/Model for codable:

```
struct BeerStyles : Codable {
  struct BeerStyleKey : CodingKey {
    var stringValue: String
    init?(stringValue: String) {
      self.stringValue = stringValue
    }
    var intValue: Int? { return nil }
    init?(intValue: Int) { return nil }

    static let description = BeerStyleKey(stringValue: "description")!
  }

  struct BeerStyle : Codable {
    let name: String
    let description: String
  }

  let beerStyles : [BeerStyle]
}
```

Decoder:

```
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: BeerStyleKey.self)

    var styles: [BeerStyle] = []
    for key in container.allKeys {
        let nested = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: BeerStyleKey.self,
            forKey: key)
        let description = try nested.decode(String.self,
            forKey: .description)
        styles.append(BeerStyle(name: key.stringValue,
            description: description))
    }

    self.beerStyles = styles
}
```

This example is from https://benscheirman.com/2017/06/swift-json/ and I'm trying to apply it to my json structure.

Comment: A good stack overflow question needs not just what you're wanting to accomplish, but also what you've already tried.  For more information see [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Something along the lines of json?["AAPL"]["quote"] . and json?["AAPL"][1]["chart"]

Comment: What are the contents of quote, news and chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code  ...:)

```
    Alamofire.request("", method: .get, encoding: JSONEncoding.default) .responseJSON { response in
            if response.result.isSuccess{
                let json = response.result.value! as? [String : Any] ?? [:]

                for (key, value) in json {

                //here key will be your apple , fb

                let valueofkey = value as? [String:Any] ?? [:]
                let quote = valueofkey["quote"] as? [String:Any] ?? [:]
                let news = valueofkey["news"] as? [Any] ?? []
                let chart = valueofkey["chart"] as? [Any] ?? []


            }

            }
        }
```

I hope it will work for you ... :)

Comment: Thank you, this does work with some slight modification.

Answer (score 1):

If the contents of `quote`, `news` and `chart` have same type, i.e. assuming that `quote` is of type `[String:String]` and `news` and chart are of type `[String]`, you can use **`Codable`** as well.

*Example:*

With the below model,

```
struct Model: Decodable {
    let quote: [String:String]
    let news: [String]
    let chart: [ String]
}
```

Now, you can parse the JSON like so,

```
do {
    let response = try JSONDecoder().decode([String:Model].self, from: data)
    print(response)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```